# I am try to select a table that is within a declared and set table in SQL but receive a syntax error

Tags: sql, set, declare

I recieve a syntax error with using the folloiwing code:

```
DECLARE @Test_Table nvarchar(255)
SET @Test_Table = 'Test'
Select *
From @Test_Table.dbo.Property
```

Any help with this issue would be appreciated

Comment: The `from` clause should contain a table reference, not a string.  The two are not the same thing, so just use the table rather than a string.  And, you need to explain what you want to do.  The question is quite confusing (as short as it is):  you have a variable called `@Test_Table` and yet you are using it in the position where the *database* goes in the three-part naming scheme.

Comment: Your use of the three-part naming scheme is incorrect even if what you were trying to do was acceptable. The three-part name is comprised of <databaseName>.dbo.<tableName>.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to use variables in SQL Server, and you appear to be trying to do both at once.  Try one of the following:

```
DECLARE @Test_Variable NVARCHAR(255)
SET @Test_Variable = 'Test'
SELECT @Test_Variable AS Property


DECLARE @Test_Table Table
  (
    Property NVARCHAR(255)
  )

INSERT INTO @Test_Table
  (
    Property
  )
VALUES 
    ('Test' )

SELECT Property FROM @Test_Table
```